# GDB run command starts the child process rather than the parent

Tags: gdb, fork

I start gdb as following: `gdb --args parentExecutable LotsOfArgsForParent`

I also run: `set follow-fork-mode child`

*parentExecutable* forks at some point and executes a *childExecutable* with some arguments. I debug the child for a while. Then, I use the *run* command of gdb to restart the *parentExecutable* with the arguments given in the beginning. However, instead, the *childExecutable* restarts -- from scratch without any arguments. How can I make gdb start the parent with the arguments provided in the beginning?

Comment: I'm guessing a bit, but I expect it is because it the the active process. Try the command "info inferiors" to list the processes being debugged, then type "inferior n" to make the parent process be the active/selected process. Then I'd expect run to restart the parent, though I bet it won't kill the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually *two* modes to pay attention to in this scenario.  One mode is `follow-fork-mode`, which tells gdb what to do when the inferior forks.  However, there is also `follow-exec-mode`, which tells gdb how to handle an `exec` call.

The default setting for `follow-exec-mode` is `same`, which tells gdb to reuse the current inferior for the exec'd process.  In this situation, once the child process stops, `run` will re-run the child.

What you want, instead, is `set follow-exec-mode new`.  In this mode, gdb will make a new inferior in response to the exec.  Then, when you want to re-run the original executable, you can switch back to the first inferior (use `info inferior` to get a list and the `inferior` command to select one).  Then `run` will re-run the original.

Another way to do all this is multi-inferior debugging, using `set detach-on-fork off`.  However, in my experience, this mode is still a bit flaky.  Once it works, though, I think it will be the preferred approach.